# How to see how much memory is in use because of single program

Tags: terminal, memory-limit

I just made a program in c++ . i just wanted to know when i run it and give it the inputs , how much memory does it use . for example , if i want to know how long it takes for that program to give me the answer , i should type :

```
time ./a.out
```

And then program launches normally .And it will show you how long it takes for that program to give you the answer .

I searched about it in the internet ,I've founded how to set memory limit for programs (tasks) in terminal. but i couldn't find anything about seeing details of memory using for a task.
How can i see how much memory does this program use to output the answer for those inputs ?

Comment: On Windows you should be able to see that with the monitoring tool (task manager) (assuming you are using windows)